# PFUser.currentUser vs String

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I'm working on iOS swift with Parse. I've a code snippet as following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var currUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    var prefQuery = PFQuery(className: "preferences")
    prefQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: currUser)
```

...

The above codes gives me nothing although I've one record in 'preference' table for the current user. But it returns a row when I use as :
 ... `prefQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: "Kale")`

I'm confused what's wrong with using `PFUser.currentUser()` method to compare with a string?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.username
```

but because it is a optional you will need to unwrap the best way to do it is

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username{
    //Query user 
    println("Found user \(user)")
} else {
    //Error handle
    println("No user logged")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and I think PFUser.currentUser() is not of type NSString, you're getting confused with it. It contains dictionary of user information. Instead, get the valueofkey of it. I think the key should be username.
So, replace this :

```
prefQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: currUser.username)
```

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Thank you loads for prompt response. Yes, it worked!